# Get the average for all columns only including values that meet a condition

Tags: r

I'm trying to sum all columns at once by using this condition: find only values greater than 5 then divide by the length of the column. But it did not work.

Here is what I did:

x1 is only one column in my data and I have 100 columns.

```
#create data frame
df <- data.frame(x1 = c(7, 3, 1, 9, 12, 8),
                 x2 = c(7, 5, 6, 1, 4, 4))

reault1<- sum(df$x1>5)/length(df$x1)
#7 is greater than 5
#9 is greater than 5
#12 is greater than 5
#8 is greater than 5
# which means 4 times. then 4/total numbers which is 6
view(reault1) #  .66%
```

Comment: The question is not clear. If your goal is to find a percentage for a column, this works:
`subset(df, x1 >5) |> transform(pct=x1/sum(x1))`.

Comment: thanks but I'm getting an error Error: unexpected '>' in "subset

Comment: What is the answer that you want?

Comment: Thanks @Elin I want the result to be .66. Please see the post. I just update it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

You can just use `colMeans` on the logical condition:

```
colMeans(df > 5)

#        x1        x2 
# 0.6666667 0.3333333
```

Or with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ mean(.x > 5)))
```

**Original Answer**

It's a little unclear what the expected output should be. To get the sum of all values greater than 5 for each column, then we can first find the values that are greater than 5 (i.e., `mydata > 5`). Then, we can compare to the original dataframe using `*`, which will change the logical to a 0 or 1 if meets the condition or not (so in reality we are just multiplying by 0 or 1). Then, we can get the sum of the column.

```
mydata <- mtcars[1:10, 1:5]

colSums(mydata * (mydata > 5))
    
#   mpg    cyl   disp     hp   drat 
# 203.7   46.0 2086.1 1228.0    0.0
```

If you just want to get the mean using the full number of rows, then we can just use `colMeans` with the same logic:

```
colMeans(mydata * (mydata > 5))

#   mpg    cyl   disp     hp   drat 
# 20.37   4.60 208.61 122.80   0.00
```

However, if you are wanting to divide by the number of values greater than 5, then we could do something like this:

```
apply(mydata, 2, function(x)
  sum(x * (x > 5)) / sum(x > 5))
```

Comment: thank you @AndrewGB I re-edit the question sorry for confusing you. I guess your latest answer is close but does not give me the right result. however, I like how each column outputs each result as individual output.

Comment: @catcat Oh okay, so you are just wanting the proportion of times that the values are greater than 5 in each column. In that case, it is much simpler; you can just use `colMeans` on the logical condition. I've updated my answer and put that at  the top.